# Cannot apply textTheme inside AppBarTheme in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I am trying to use `textTheme` inside `AppBarTheme` in flutter but when I run my application, nothing changes. Also my editor says that `'textTheme' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. This property is no longer used, please use toolbarTextStyle and titleTextStyle instead.`

Here is my code snippet:

```
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter App',
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
      primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
    ).copyWith(
      secondary: Colors.amber,
    ),
    fontFamily: 'QuickSand',
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
            headline6: const TextStyle(
              fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
              fontSize: 20,
            ),
          ),
    ),
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
```

I am a newbie and just started learning Flutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [`textTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBarTheme-class.html) → `TextTheme`?
> This property is deprecated, please use [`toolbarTextStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBarTheme/toolbarTextStyle.html) and [`titleTextStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBarTheme/titleTextStyle.html) instead.

Use `titleTextStyle`

```dart
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
titleTextStyle:
    Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.titleTextStyle?.copyWith(
          fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
),
```

If you like to use `headline6` it is coming from `textTheme`.

```dart
appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
  titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6?.copyWith(
        fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
),
```

Comment: question. The first example if i use just titleTextStyle?.copyWith() and change the color only, why doesnt the font size look the same as the default (20). it is pretty small like size 14. I assumed copyWith() means copying everything except the one you specify inside the method which will be overridden.

Comment: @chitgoks it would be easy for me if you create a new question with  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
          toolbarTextStyle:
              ThemeData.light().textTheme.headline6!.copyWith(fontFamily: 'OpenSans'),titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 20) ,
```