# Error: The getter 'textTheme' isn't defined for the class 'AppBarTheme'. and No named parameter with the name 'accentColor'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_neumorphic-3.2.0/lib/src/widget/app_bar.dart:183:29: Error: The getter 'textTheme' isn't defined for the class 'AppBarTheme'.
 - 'AppBarTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart' ('../../../MycodingLibs/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'textTheme'.
        style: (appBarTheme.textTheme?.headline5 ??
                            ^^^^^^^^^
../../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_neumorphic-3.2.0/lib/src/widget/app.dart:89:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'accentColor'.
      accentColor: theme.variantColor,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../MycodingLibs/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme_data.dart:290:11: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  factory ThemeData({
          ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/home/corecreater/MycodingLibs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1201

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/home/corecreater/MycodingLibs/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

It's old project in my opinion and i don't know what to do.
I tried to update all packages in pubspec.yaml.
there is no Code error as per Android Studio.
I think it's problem of flutter version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot apply textTheme inside AppBarTheme in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72548446/cannot-apply-texttheme-inside-appbartheme-in-flutter)

Answer (score -1):

It can be a problem for your flutter_neumorphic package, which may be you used before another projects. If this issue happens, then you can run this command on your terminal.

```
flutter pub cache clean
```

After running the command, the pub cache on your computer will be cleared, and any previously downloaded packages will need to be re-downloaded when needed.

Note: If you are not using Flutter, you can replace '**flutter pub cache clean**' with **'pub cache clean'** to clear the pub cache for regular Dart packages.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that the main culprit was flutter_neumorphic. I'll use an alternative package.

Comment: this command corrupted my flutter sdk

Comment: @HachemMohamedMahmoud this command clean pub cache from flutter sdk. After this you need to run flutter pub get for all your projects to get packages and plugins.

Comment: i did run flutter pub get -v and flutter packages get --verbose  then it stuck at some point and takes forever i had to reinstall my flutter again i wasted a lot of time on this